# Change class by evaluating innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the style of a `<span>` by changing its class.  I'm evaluating its text value and want it to change the className to 'red' if it's less than 97.7, or to 'green' if it's anything else.  I'm evaluating all  `<span>` of class "qadata".

```
function changeColor() {

var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('span').getElementsByClassName('qadata');

for (var i=0, len=cells.length; i<len; i++) {
    if (parseFloat(cells[i].innerHTML) < 97.7){
        cells[i].className = 'red';
    }
    else {
        cells[i].className = 'green';
    }
}

}
```

I'm trying to do this in the following HTML table:

```
<table datasrc='#QA' class="qa">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Period</th>
      <th>Safety</th>
      <th>Quality</th>
      <th>Shipping</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="leftcolumn"><span datafld='Period' width=100%></span></td>
      <td><span datafld='Safety' width=100% class="safety"></span></td>
      <td><span datafld='Quality' width=100% class="qadata"></span></td>
      <td><span datafld='Shipping' width=100% class="qadata"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

The data is populated using another function prior to calling changeColor().  This is a corporate intranet site, so I'm currently stuck using ie8 or ie10.  JavaScript is preferable to jQuery in this instance.

I've been doing HTML and CSS for years, but never got into JavaScript until recently.  I tried searching but haven't found a method posted here that works.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is not supported in IE8 -> http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname

Comment: nor is `getElementsByClassName` a function on the object returned by `getElementsByTagName`. If you want a list of all spans with class qdata, use `document.querySelectorAll('span.qdata')`.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected that getElementsByClassName was part of my problem. I've updated my code to reflect document.querySelectorAll('span.qadata'), but I'm still not getting the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

I created a jsfiddle that seems to work. I just used the:

```
   document.querySelectorAll('span.qadata')
```

It changes the class names for the spans with class qadata. http://jsfiddle.net/mYUjL/

Comment: It might be worth modifying that fiddle to a) have some data in the fields for the eval to work on and b) some styles specified for those classes to prove its actually working. I'm not sure how you judged that it worked on the fiddle you've given since it doesn't seem to actually do anything...

Comment: I added data to the fiddle to ensure one red and one green class.  It works in the fiddle.  It doesn't work on my browser.  Perhaps this is an issue with internet explorer?  We'll be switching to a Chrome-based display system in the future, perhaps that will solve the issue.

Comment: I just tested in IE8 and it worked once I added: <!doctype html>, you also might want to check your browser mode and document mode